# How to prevent double quotes when using the verbatim package and fontenc?

Tags: verbatim

Is there a way to disable LaTeX's transformation of all double quotes e.g. `''` ``` `` ``` `<< >>` into formatted double quotes when using the `verbatim` package in conjunction with `fontenc` and redefining `\verbatim@font` such as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\ttfamily}%
\makeatother
\newenvironment{code}
  {\topsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt\endgraf\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
0x3333 << 1
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

The above turns `<<`  into a formatted french quote. If I don't use the `fontenc` package, or if I don't redefine `\verbatim@font` then it displays ok. For my document, I want to redefine the font (mainly to have better granularity than `\small`, `\tiny` etc) and I use the `fontenc` package because other parts of the document otherwise display wrong fonts.

Can I disable double quotes inside `\verbatim` or globally?

I could also ditch the `verbatim` package, but I want to define a command around verbatim text, and you can't do that by default.

It all works apart from those pesky quotes ... any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a complete small document that shows the problem (all questions should have such an example). What you describe is not the default behaviour, so it depends how you have defined `<`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Comment: You're right. I edited the question and provided a full example. The problem manifests itself in conjunction with the fontenc package and redefining \verbatim@font. Any ideas to prevent the formatting of << ?

Answer (score 2):

Doh, I forgot to RTFM! It's in the [manual](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/verbatim/verbatim.pdf) section 3.2 which discusses `\verbatim@font`

To fix my problem, change the redefinition of `\verbatim@font` to the following:

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\ttfamily
  \hyphenchar\font\m@ne
  \let\do\do@noligs
  \verbatim@nolig@list}
\makeatother
```

Comment: yes if you redefine verbatim not to do verbatim, it stops doing verbatim +1 glad you got it working;-)

Comment: Indeed. Not enough coffee today.

Answer (score 1):

TeX-style ligatures for character sequences such as `<<` and `>>` are enabled in T1-encoded fonts even for monotype font faces. The following remedy should work: Insert the instructions

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt* }
```

in the preamble.

Loading the `microtype` package may be a good idea in any case...

Comment: Thanks for this. The `microtype` package is required for `\DisableLigatures`. I wanted a solution without having to use extra packages, but this is useful as it disables ligatures for all tt* fonts, including inline (text) which is quite handy for my current use case.